# how to read PWM (pulse width modulation signals)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, operating-systems, signal, linux-device-driver

I am developing embedded Linux driver level program in Toradex Apalis Tk1 development board with IXORA career board, and with operating system is Embedded Linux.

I need to know that how to read PWM signals in that board/in Linux/in general Linux development board, and how to calculate duty cycle of PWMS signals?

Someone please me out!!

Comment: What kind of hardware do you plan to use to capture the signals? What do the drivers for that hardware look like? Which format will the captured data be in? How precise do the measurements need to be (e.g., could you charge a capacity with the PWM and just measure that as an approximation, or would that be too crude?) What frequency range does the PWM have?

Comment: actually i am getting PWM signals from RC , and i connected that rc to gpio lines of apalis TK1 board,it is embedded linux development board